# Is possible to mark test as failed from end_suite method in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I'm creating a library where the results of the actuall tests we get at the end of the suite. The results are collected inside the custom Listener component in `end_suite` method.

For example, we have two tests: `Test 1` and `Test 2`. After test suite run, in the results, we see both tests as passed. But actually, `Test 2` is failed which we see inside `end_suite`.

If I raise an exception at the `end_suite` it doesn't show any difference and tests are marked as passed anyway.

Is there a way to backtrack the status of tests to give them proper status? Or maybe you could propose a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really undersand your answer, but you can add Teardown at the end of your tests :

```
[Teardown]      Run Keyword If      '${TEST_STATUS}' == 'FAIL'       Fatal Error
```

Else, define a keyword in your test suite :

```
*** Variables ***
${SUITE_ERROR}=      ${False}
```

Then you can call a keyword at end of each test or during it (here named Suite Error)

```
[Teardown]      Run Keyword If      '${TEST_STATUS}' == 'FAIL'       Suite Error
```

Here is the keyword :

```
Suite Error
[Documentation]     Triggers an error if the current operation
Set Global Variable     ${SUITE_ERROR}      ${True}
```

At the end of Test suite, call suite teardown :

```
*** Settings ***
...
Suite Teardown      Test Teardown

*** Keywords ***
Test Teardown
# At the end of the Test Suite, if there is a FAIL, STOP all next tests
Run Keyword If      '${SUITE_ERROR}' == '${True}'       Fatal Error
```

Hope i help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not what I needed. I'm creating a library that extends robot framework keywords. And I need to back propagate tests results from `Listener.end_suite` to robotframework logger